# Display the brand and products first when user revisits the site which is browse by user in last time

Tags: magento-1.9, product, recently-viewed

For my `Magento 1.9.1`, I want to save the products and brands which is visited by the user and `show those Products first when he revisits the site`. I have tried with recently view block but it's not working for me.

Can anyone please let me know how it is possible?

Comment: Recently viewed product will not work for you. I think this extention can help you. https://store.plumrocket.com/recently-viewed-products-magento-extension.html

Comment: Also you can do it with logic as : when customer visit the product you can enter product id and customer ip in new table and save it. So when same customer visit the product then you can match ip and display product from table.